# Solr equivalent of trivial SQL filter

Tags: sql, solr

Is there a Solr equivalent for WHERE 1 = 0 in SQL? Would `fq=-id:[* TO *]` suffice to force an empty result set to be returned (and `fq=*:*` to filter nothing)?

I looked extensively at the Apache Solr documentation, especially the function query section, but wasn’t able to find a definitive answer.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do such a filter in the 1st place?

Comment: I'm working on a service with a method that creates a dummy filter expression in SQL and am trying to replicate that functionality for Solr.

Comment: `*:* -*:*` should effectivly give you "all documents, minus the set making up all documents" - so no documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use two opposite filter queries:

`fq=field:value&fq=-field:value`

First filter will only select documents having `value` and second filter will keep none of them.